# Coinvariant of algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

If $G$ acts on $C_c^{\infty}(G)\otimes C_c^{\infty}(G)$ diagonally by right translation, is the coinvariant $(C_c^{\infty}(G)\otimes C_c^{\infty}(G))_{R(G^{\Delta})}$ isomorphic to $C_c^{\infty}(G)$ as vector space?